# PC restarted or died when computing

Tags: 12.04, restart, matlab

I just upgraded 12.04 64-bit. When I run some code in matlab, the computer is always dead or it restarts. I couldn't figure out the reason.

Although video card on the motherboard is only 32MB, I have Nvidia video card and choose primary video card to be other in BIOS.

Can you give me some suggestion?  Maybe first, I can start with some test to see the health of computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install memtest, and run it from the bootloader. This will detect hardware issues with the main memory. If matlab hits a defective memory section, which would normally not be used, this can easily cause the problems described.

Also keep a watch on memory usage and CPU temperature while runnung matlab. If the memory rund full the OS kernel normally starts killing off processes, normally this doesn't cause a cold reboot though. If the CPU overheats this can be the cause of system freeze or reboot.